# I am having a problem with the floating property.Both elements are floated right

Tags: css, css-float

[I am want to get the book repair button on left of the Svg button.

`button{ float:right; background-color: #155FCC; padding: 10px 25px; color:white; border-radius:20px; box-shadow: none; border: none; } svg{ float: right; clear:right; height:55px; width:55px; }`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alpBG.png)

[This is the type of output that i am looking for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtKRo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the order of the elements in the HTML.

```
svg{ float: right; clear:right; height:55px; width:55px; }
button{ float:right; background-color: #155FCC; padding: 10px 25px; color:white; border-radius:20px; box-shadow: none; border: none; }
```